# SSRS 2012 Alternating Group Colour within rows

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

hi I have a simple SSRS 2012 report with a table. All the data is displayed via store procedure. There is no grouping i.e

Dept Name Age
**ClassA Bob 15

ClassA Sue 16

ClassA Jo  15**
ClassB Sam 15
ClassB Jack 15
ClassB Mary 16
**ClassC Pete 15

ClassC Sue 16**
ClassD Jo  15
ClassD Mary 14
ClassD Jack 14

I would like rows colour block for each 'group' to change i.e White and then Blue

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following expression (Backgroud , Text ) where ever you want your report to change colours.

```
=Switch(
        Fields!Dept.Value = "ClassA" , "Red"
      , Fields!Dept.Value = "ClassB" , "Orange"
      , Fields!Dept.Value = "ClassC" , "Green"
      , Fields!Dept.Value = "ClassD" , "Yellow"
      )
```

Comment: where you want to change the colour, say if you want to change the backgroud colour, then in design mode select the row and then in Properties window click on Background colour , click on Expression and put this code in there. Save report and execute it. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

In `Report`-`Report Properties...` on the `Code` tab insert the following code:

```
Dim LastDept AS String = ""
Dim Color AS String

Function GetColor(Dept As String) AS String
  if (Dept <> LastDept) Then
    if (Color = "White") Then
      Color = "PowderBlue"
    Else
      Color = "White"
    End If
  End If
End Function
```

Then set the `BackgroundColor` expression of your row to

```
=Code.GetColor(Fields!Dept.Value)
```

The will toggle the background colour of your rows between White and PowderBlue whenever the department changes.

Comment: Thanks - getting this error - The blacgroundColor expression contains an error - BC30451  getcolor is not declared'

Comment: ssrs background color expression cannot find function getcolor

Comment: Sorry, error in function call, try the revised version with `Code.` in front of the function call

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for a solution to the same thing for a while and just stumbled across this solution.

Adding the following expression to the background colour property of the row that is being grouped will alternate the colours of the groups between Gainsboro and White.

```
=IIF(RunningValue(Fields!Category.Value,CountDistinct, Nothing) MOD 2 = 1, "Gainsboro", "White")
```

Where Fields!Category.Value is the value from your stored procedure you are grouping on.

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Thanks

Comment: I've only been able to get this to work on the first page of my report.  Subsequent pages are all white.

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this for various alternate colour scenarios.

In the custom code for the report:

```
Private CountArr(,) AS String
Private eleID AS Integer
Public Function AlternateColours(OddCol AS String, EvenCol AS String, RowID AS String, UserID AS Integer)

    If UserID > eleID
        eleID = UserID
        ReDim Preserve CountArr(1,eleID -1)
    End If

    If CountArr(0,UserID-1) <> RowID
        CountArr(0,UserID-1) = RowID
        CountArr(1, UserID-1) += 1
    End If

    If CountArr(1, UserID-1) MOD 2 <> 0
        Return OddCol
    Else
        Return EvenCol
    End If

End Function

Public Function ResetAlternateColours(Value AS String)

    ReDim CountArr(1, 0)
    eleID = 0
    Return Value

End Function
```

**Instructions**

OddCol is the first colour, EvenCol is the alternate colour and RowID is a string that determines when a Row change has occurred -- This can be any value that correctly identifies a new row such as a concatenation of field values or even just an arbitrary string for rows that aren't grouped. (For your requirements your parameter would be Fields!Dept.Value)

UserID is an Integer value chosen by the user to identify where the row is located in the array.  Recommended use is to provide numbers in the order that the report is rendered starting from 1.

FYI: Reports are rendered in reading order i.e. Left-to-right, top-to-bottom.

The reset function is also included in the event you have areas where you would like the alternating colours to start from the beginning.  For my personal use, I had it take a string as a value and return that value after the reset.

=Code.ResetAlternateColours(Fields!Total.Value)

It is not necessary and you can remove the return value from the function and then just add it to the end of the cell.

=Fields!Total.Value + Code.ResetAlternateColours()

Just remember rendering orders and you should be fine.

This function can be used for columns, rows, cells and anything else you can think of as long as you remember the render order and increment the UserID accordingly.

**For your use:**

=Code.AlternateColours("White", "Blue", Fields!Dept.Value, 1)